# fatal error: EGL/egl.h: No such file or directory

Tags: sdl, sdl-2, egl

[image]

I had compiled SDL 2.0 source.
First, I commended 'cmake ../ -G "MinGW Makefiles" on console.
Second, I commended 'make'. but error is happned.

```
fatal error: EGL/egl.h: No such file or directory
```

Where can I download EGL/egl header and library?

My environment :
Windows 10 home 64bit
MinGW

Comment: EGL website says Pablo (https://sourceforge.net/projects/pablo/) provides the headers. However, I'm not sure it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `CMakeCache.txt` and `CMakeFiles` and try

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DVIDEO_OPENGLES=0 ../
mingw32-make
```